# Remove .idea directory from all previous git commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have ~50 commits in my local Git repository. Accidentally in the initial commit, I have included `.idea` folder, now I have to remove all files from that folder right from the initial commit. Is it possible by any chance to achieve this?

I have tried the following commands but converting as separate commits without linking to previous commits:

```
$ echo '.idea' >> .gitignore
$ git rm -r --cached .idea
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit --amend
```

Comment: Amending git history is dangerous stuff. Once you've committed & pushed, it's more or less set in stone unless you're prepared to do some repo surgery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter-branch` to do this:

```
cp -r .idea .idea.bak
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r .idea' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This will remove `.idea` from all past commits.
After this, you can update the `.gitignore` file as you did,
to avoid adding `.idea` in the future by mistake.

Note that this rewrites the history of your repository.
If it's public and there are other collaborators,
then think carefully if this is really worth it to do.

See more details at
https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Comment: Thanks janos, i do have another doubt how do i remove all multiple occurrences of .DSStore files

Comment: @Venkat `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git ls-files | grep /\\.DSStore$ | xargs git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Comment: Hi , what is the harmful of that if we have .idea in remote repository?